# Passing argument to view function from template without exposing it in URL

Tags: django, django-urls

How should arguments be passed from template to view function without appearing in URL?

I am familiar with the usual way to pass arguments to view function through template:

Template

```html
<a href="{% url 'redirection' pk %}">Perform</a>
```

URL:

```
url(r'^redirect/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.redirection, name='redirection'),
```

View Function:

```
def redirection(request, pk):
    # code of function
```

This method exposes the pk variable in URL. Is there any other way to perform this without exposing this variable in URL?

Can [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) be used to perform the above task? If yes, then how should the code in template be changed to perform this?

Comment: You would either need to do a POST request or use session variables to pass variables without putting them in the URL.

Comment: also you can send variable as GET parameter

Comment: @vorujack, can you please elaborate?

Comment: What's the problem with exposing pk in a template?

Comment: No problem in exposing in the template. Just, do not wish to expose in URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you must write two function to encode and decode values like this:

```
import base64
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

AKEY = 'mysixteenbytekey' # AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)


def encode(message):
    obj = AES.new(AKEY, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(obj.encrypt(message))


def decode(cipher):
    obj2 = AES.new(AKEY, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return obj2.decrypt(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(cipher))
```

then when you want pass parameter pk to template encode it like this:

```
return render(...{
     ...
     'encode_pk': encode(str(pk)),
     })
```

then you can pass it as GET query. when you creating your URL in your template add an `?` to url and your parameter to it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'redirection' %}?pk={{ encode_pk }}">Perform</a>
```

in your view you can get this parameter like this

```
def redirection(request):
    pk = decode(request.GET.get("pk"))
    # do anything with pk
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. It generates this url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/redirect/?pk=8

Comment: Where 8 is the pk passed. I tried exactly as you mentioned. Can you suggest some other ways? or any suggestion regarding how to make the above method work if I am missing something

Comment: you must update your URLS.py and remove PK parameter from it. `url(r'^redirect/$', views.redirection, name='redirection'),`

Comment: I had changed urls.py to the same as you mentioned.

Comment: Whats happend when you do these changes. return nothing. raise exception or ... ?

Comment: It still generates same url 127.0.0.1:8000/redirect/?pk=8 and works fine, the page loads with pk=8 and everything works exactly as expected, EXCEPT that pk is still appearing in url.

Comment: if you want to pass some argument from client to server have 3 way. GET - POST - HEADER and COOKIE. GET are appear in URL.(you can encode and decode value to hide it. POST are not in URL but you must sent it with script. HEADER and COOKIE not suggested.

Comment: I believe I would like to use GET with encoding and decoding value to hide it.

Comment: Please write your views on ways of encoding,decoding value and passing through GET. I will accept that answer.

Comment: answer updated. you can use any encoding and decoding function